# Outlook web add-in Inactive buttons in downloaded .ics appointment

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Colleagues, maybe anyone knows why web add-in buttons are disabled on downloaded .ics appointment on ribbon, and maybe anyone knows the solution to grand access to downloaded appointment in outlook via web add-in, or it’s just a feature those we should accept?
[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6umGL.png)
Maybe I can add some xml tag, to solve it...
My google research doesn’t gave any results

If I’ll save appointment, it’s work, but there is not a solution

Only one tag with permission in my manifest.xml that I have now is:

```xml
    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```

I expect that add-in should work with external .ics appointments

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to https://outlook.uservoice.com/ .

Comment: Hi Eugene, thank you for comment. As I understand you meant that there no any solutions for this case, only make a feature request in userVoice

Comment: Yep. Exactly so.

Comment: Created request on userVoice - https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/38221243-enable-access-to-downloaded-ics-appointment-file
Eugene, thanks for the idea!